# Quickbooks custom field for computing a value

Tags: quickbooks

I'm have a newb question with Quickbooks. I'm a programmer and this shouldn't be that hard, but I'm not sure how to ask so Google isn't working for me. For projects my business bills for we charge a 50% deposit. On the invoice I'd like to have a field, above the Total, that computes 50% of the Total. How do you do that?

Comment: "I'm a programmer and this shouldn't be that hard..."- do you work for Intuit?  If you didn't program Quickbooks then you are in the same boat as the rest of who didn't  =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Custom fields are limited to non-calculated values.  Read more here:  http://qbblog.ccrsoftware.info/2008/07/custom-fields-in-quickbooks/

To do this you will need an add-on.  I would reccomend CCRQInvoice, but only because its the only one I've tried and it worked.  More here (this is an order form example, but it works):

http://ccrqblog.ccrsoftware.info/adding-calculated-fields-to-order-forms/

The product info is here:
http://www.ccrsoftware.com/CCRQInvoice/InvoiceQ.htm

Answer (score 0):

Another option is FormCalc SST for QuickBooks. It lets you set up Excel-compatible calculations, then applies them to a QuickBooks invoice on the fly. 
http://www.goflagship.com/sst.html

FormCalc SST and CCRQInvoice work differently:  FormCalc SST is better for real-time use, with calculations performed as each invoice is being entered or edited, but CCRQInvoice is better for processing a batch of already-entered invoices, all at once.